# how to show multiple record in one table row

Tags: php, mysql, loops

How to show multiple record in one table row ?
I'm not good explain using words, so i'll use an example :

```
Work No. | Product No. | Product Name | Qty | Item No. | Item Name | Qty |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
W00001   | P0000001    | Product_1    |  6  | I000001  | Item_1    |  2  |
         |             |              |     | I000002  | Item_2    |  2  |
         |             |              |     | I000003  | Item_3    |  2  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                           Total   :  6  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
W00002   | P0000002    | Product_2    |  7  | I000001  | Item_1    |  3  |
         |             |              |     | I000004  | Item_4    |  4  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                           Total   :  7  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

as you can see, product is made from multiple items. So far, i can make more less like example above but my question is how to display item like example above. I want to show items in one row. How to show that using php ?

Comment: Just Suggestion: *atleast store as comma separated values if you dont want to normalize*

Comment: Hands off from misusing database by adding comma separated values. You don't want that.

Comment: Do you also want to store in mysql in one table? Or you have multiple tables in mysql and you just want to print using php like that?

Comment: Better, you can use another table, or you can store with json_encoded.

Comment: @devpro I'm sorry, i forgot a little detail. I want to show it using php.. sorry

Comment: Just use a PHP loop to handle display issues

Comment: @DanielDudas print using php..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have 2 tables: one for products and one for items you simply have to loop throw the products one and for each product get all the items needed for that product and display there.

Your code needs to look something like this:

```
$products = get_products_from_db(); //How you normal get products from db.
foreach($products as $product) {
    $items = get_items_by_product_from_db($product['id']);   //get from db all items for a product.
    //foreach product we will need a new row.

    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td>{$product['work_no']}</td>";    //and all the normal cells like this.
    //for item no. we will create a cell and inside it we will foreach items.
    echo "<td>";
    foreach($items as $item) {
        echo $item['item_no'] . '<br/>';//Or how it's called in db.
    }
    echo "</td>";
    //Exact the same with name and quantity.
    //For quantity also keep a counter so you can display the total
    echo '</tr>';
    //After this row create a new tr to display the total. I think you know how to do this.
}
```

Comment: Is it same with while() inside while() ?

Comment: @Teddy You can use `while` too if it's easier for you. The complexity will be the same.

Comment: Hi Daniel, i've tried your algo using while but, the result for item it printed to the left not below..

Comment: Did that too, still same result.